# Yii not merging criteria correctly - always using AND even though I pass OR

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, join, yii

I'm using multiple nested search criteria in Yii to select a model called libraries. The conditions are as follows:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = 't.id, t.barcode_1_id, t.barcode_2_id, t.library_type_id, t.qc_pass'; 
    $criteria->order = 'patient.id DESC, t.id DESC'; 
    $criteria->together = true;
    $with=array(
            'isolates'=>array(
              'select'=>false,
            ),
            'samples'=>array(
              'select'=>'samples.id, samples.sample_preservation_id, samples.tumor',
            ),
            'patient'=>array(
              'select'=>'patient.id',
            ),
            'flowcells'=>array(
                'select'=>'flowcells.id,flowcells.serial_id',
            ),
            'libraryType'=>array(
                'select'=>'libraryType.id,libraryType.short_name',
            ),
            'samplePreservation'=>array(
              'select'=>'samplePreservation.name',
            ),
            'program'=>array(
                'select'=>false,
                'condition'=>'program.name NOT LIKE "%Lab%"',
            ),
            'runs'=>array(
              'select'=>'runs.id',
            )
          );

    // by run ID
    if (is_array($runs) && (! empty($runs))) {
        $runCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $runCriteria->addInCondition("runs.id", $runs, 'OR');
        $criteria->mergeWith($runCriteria, $operator='OR');
        $something=true;
    }

    // libraries without patients
    if ( ($patients=='Unassigned') || (is_array($patients) && in_array('Unassigned',$patients)) ) {
        $unassCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $unassCriteria->addCondition('patient.id IS NULL');
        $criteria->mergeWith($unassCriteria, $operator='OR');
        $something=true;
    }

    if ( ($patients=='QC Pass') || (is_array($patients) && in_array('QC Pass',$patients)) ) {
        $qcCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $qcCriteria->addCondition('t.qc_pass = 1',$operator='AND');
        $qcCriteria->addCondition('t.created BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()','AND');
        $criteria->mergeWith($qcCriteria, $operator='OR');
        $something=true;
    }

    if ( ($patients=='Ready for Flowcell') || (is_array($patients) && in_array('Ready for Flowcell',$patients)) ) {
        $readyCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $readyCriteria->addCondition('flowcells.id IS NULL',$operator='AND');
        $readyCriteria->addCondition('runs.current_pipeline_node_id = 7',$operator='AND');
        $criteria->mergeWith($readyCriteria, $operator='OR');
        $something=true;
    }

    if (is_array($patients) && (! empty($patients))) {
        $ptArr= array_diff($patients, array('QC Pass','Unassigned','Ready for Flowcell'));
        $ptCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $ptCriteria->addInCondition("patient.id", $ptArr,$operator='OR');
        if ($ptArr) $criteria->mergeWith($ptCriteria, $operator='OR');
        $something=true;
    }



    if ($something) $librariesModel=Libraries::model()->with($with)->findAll($criteria);
```

Then I format these results for a view.

Problem is Yii is ignoring my $operator='OR' and always using AND instead of OR.  Here's the WHERE clause this generates:

(SELECT and JOIN look fine)

...

```
WHERE 
(
    (

        ( (patient.id IS NULL) AND ( (t.qc_pass = 1) AND (t.created BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()) ) ) 

        AND ( (flowcells.id IS NULL) AND (runs.current_pipeline_node_id = 7) )

    ) 

    AND (patient.id IN (:ycp0, :ycp1))

) 

AND (program.name NOT LIKE "%Lab%") 



ORDER BY patient.id DESC, t.id DESC, inventory_id ASC
```

Any idea why Yii is not letting me merge these criteria using "OR"?  My goal is to have several parenthetical expressions which contain AND inside, but are not exclusive. The mergeWith methods should be adding those criteria to the WHERE clause using OR, not AND.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was looking at documentation for a newer version of CDbCriteria.  It should be a true or false value:

```
public function mergeWith($criteria,$useAnd=true)
{
    $and=$useAnd ? 'AND' : 'OR';
    .....
```

Must be used as follows:

```
$criteria->mergeWith($unassCriteria, false);
```

instead of

```
$criteria->mergeWith($unassCriteria, 'OR');
```

because 'OR' is true!